# how to enable ui interaction with visible components behind a canvas?

Tags: dart, flutter, overlay

I'm writing a flutter application and I'm trying to create a tutorial overlay, that will fully show only components that I want the user to be able to interact with.

so I extended CustomPainter class, while getting the Page's context (to get his dimensions) and a list of GlobalKeys (for elements that I want to display and to interact with)

```
Color colorBlack = Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4);

class CurvePainter extends CustomPainter{

  BuildContext context;
  List<GlobalKey> globalKeys;
  double padding;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    Path path = Path()..addRect(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight));

    Set<GlobalKey> keysSet = Set.from(globalKeys);
    keysSet.forEach((element){
      final List<double> vals = global_key_util.getArea(element);
      path = Path.combine(PathOperation.difference,
          path,
          Path()
            ..addOval(Rect.fromLTWH(vals[0]-(padding/2),vals[1]-padding/2,vals[2]+padding,vals[3]+padding)));
    });

    canvas.drawPath(path,
        Paint()..color = colorBlack);

  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate != this;
  }

  CurvePainter({this.context,this.globalKeys,this.padding=4});

}
```

so far so good... the button that I want the user to interact with is fully visible, in the `initState()` of my page I create the overlay and show it.

[image: how the app looks so far]

the problem is that I can't interact with that button!
how can I resolve this ?

thanks

Comment: Wrap your `widget` with a `gestureDetector` and use `onTap` to perform the desired action.

Comment: @KeertiPurswani - sometimes I want to have an input element visible.. so ontap won't help  with that

Comment: Can you please explain "input element visible". What code did you try?

Comment: @KeertiPurswani - I want to be able to have an overlay over all my screen and still to be able to interact with  some widgets behind it. currently I'm using ClipPath for the widgets behind it to be fully visible and to be able to interact with them. the question is.. can it be done without ClipPath so my overlay will still be visible in these areas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so.. the answer is simply not to use CustomPainter, to use `ClipPath` with `CustomClipper`.

in my case I wanted to detect when the user is clicking on the overflow, but to also allow him to interact with the visible widgets behind it.

so I created an `InvertedClipper` class that extends `CustomClipper`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
import 'HoleArea.dart';
import 'WidgetData.dart';

class InvertedClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {

  final Animation<double> animation;
  final List<WidgetData> widgetsData;
  double padding;
  Function deepEq = const DeepCollectionEquality().equals;
  List<HoleArea> areas = [];

  InvertedClipper({@required this.padding, this.animation, Listenable reclip,
      this.widgetsData}) : super(reclip: reclip) {
    if (widgetsData.isNotEmpty) {
      widgetsData.forEach((WidgetData widgetData) {
        if (widgetData.isEnabled) {
          final GlobalKey key = widgetData.key;
          if (key == null) {
        //    throw new Exception("GlobalKey is null!");
          } else if (key.currentWidget == null) {
//            throw new Exception("GlobalKey is not assigned to a Widget!");
          } else {
            areas.add(getHoleArea(key: key,shape: widgetData.shape,padding: widgetData.padding));
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    double animationValue = animation != null ? animation.value : 0;
    areas.forEach((HoleArea area) {
      switch (area.shape) {
        case WidgetShape.Oval: {
          path.addOval(Rect.fromLTWH(area.x - (((area.padding + padding) + animationValue*15) / 2), area.y - ((area.padding + padding) + animationValue*15) / 2,
              area.width + ((area.padding + padding) + animationValue*15), area.height + ((area.padding + padding) + animationValue*15)));
        }
        break;
        case WidgetShape.Rect: {
          path.addRect(Rect.fromLTWH(area.x - (((area.padding + padding) + animationValue*15) / 2), area.y - ((area.padding + padding) + animationValue*15) / 2,
              area.width + ((area.padding + padding) + animationValue*15), area.height + ((area.padding + padding) + animationValue*15)));
        }
        break;
        case WidgetShape.RRect: {
          path.addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndCorners(Rect.fromLTWH(area.x - (((area.padding + padding) + animationValue*15) / 2), area.y - ((area.padding + padding) + animationValue*15) / 2,
              area.width + ((area.padding + padding) + animationValue*15), area.height + ((area.padding + padding) + animationValue*15)),
              topLeft: Radius.circular(5.0),
              topRight: Radius.circular(5.0),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5.0),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(5.0)));
        }
        break;
      }
    });
    return path
      ..addRect(Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height))
      ..fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(InvertedClipper oldClipper) {
    return !deepEq(oldClipper.areas, areas);
  }
}
```

and I configure a `GestureDetector` before that to detect when user is clicking on overlay:

```
return GestureDetector(
                onTap: onTap,
                child: ClipPath(
                    clipper: InvertedClipper(
                      padding: defaultPadding,
                        animation: animation,
                        reclip: animationController,
                        widgetsData: widgetsData),
  ...
```